# How to add a WP_query() to my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site. Every post we have has three categorizing terms, "Location", "Topic", and "Edition". Now I want to create a dropdown menu, actually three dropdown menus, to show these terms, acting like filters. And the idea was pulling out specific posts via WP_query() when readers choose a term from the menus. Now I have the menus, and I can only get some static content return. I don't know how to integrate a WP_query into my function... Please help! Thank you so much.

One of my dropdown menus:

```
<?php

$categories = get_terms('location');

$select = "<select name='cat' id='loc' class='postform'>n";
$select.= "<option value='-1'><strong>by Location</strong></option>n";

foreach($categories as $category){
if($category->count > 0){
$select.= "<option value='".$category->slug."'>".$category->name."  </option>";}}

$select.= "</select>";

echo $select;

?>
```

My script:

```
<script>

var loc_posts = document.getElementById("loc");

var div = document.createElement("div");

 function locChange() {

    var loc = document.getElementById("loc").value;

         if ( loc_posts.options[loc_posts.selectedIndex].value !== -1 ) {

            document.getElementById("post-1998").appendChild(div);

            div.innerHTML = loc ; 

}}

 loc_posts.onchange = locChange;
</script>
```

Also don't know how to put the chosen term into my WP_query()

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => loc
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ajax in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137202/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress)

Comment: Thanks! It appears that Ajax should be the solution. But I'm new js and that post was too complicated for me...

Comment: read that answer there again; it has all you'd need... you'll just have to add your PHP code and make it respond with `function my_ajax_callback(){/* populate an array with data here; eg. with WP_Query */ die(json_encode($data));}` ...these callback functions need to be registered with WordPress core.